# website button click wont work on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to HTML + CSS and I tried to design a website from a template that I found.

One of the elements in the website is a button that should scroll down to the download section.

[image]

When the button is clicked from my computer it all works well. However, when I try to click on it from my mobile device nothing happens.

Why is that?

The code in index.html for this button is:

```
<div class="buttons" data-aos="fade-up">
    <a href="#download" class="smoothscroll button stroke">
        <span class="icon-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        Download App
    </a>
</div>
```

Which should have scrolled me down to:

```
<section id="download">
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-full">
            <h1 class="intro-header"  data-aos="fade-up">Download Our App Today!</h1>
            
            <p class="lead" data-aos="fade-up">
                Liked our App? Great! Download our App.
            </p>
            
            <ul class="download-badges">
                <li><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=.....k" title="" class="badge-googleplay" data-aos="fade-up">Play Store</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
</section>
```

The code I found for this smoothscroll is at the .js file:

```
var ssSmoothScroll = function() {

    $('.smoothscroll').on('click', function (e) {
        var target = this.hash,
        $target    = $(target);
    
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();      

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, cfg.scrollDuration, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });

    });

};
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you call `ssmoothScroll()` when the page is loaded?

Comment: Umm if I understand it right so there is no listener or something to see if the page loaded so I guess I load I call even if the page not loaded.

Comment: `$(document).ready(ssmoothScroll)`

Comment: I tried to edit this demo: https://demos.onepagelove.com/html/dazzle/ . I don't see that they have this .ready as well but on the demo, it works and in my case, it doesn't.

Comment: Putting the script at the end of the body also waits for everything to be loaded. That's what they do.